# `steveltn/https-portal` repeatedly reboots

Tags: docker

I want to build nginx inside Docker and make this https.
Therefore, I built the environment of nginx and steveltn/https-portal as follows.

```
docker run -itd  --restart=always --name lb -p 8000:80 nginx
docker network create --subnet=192.168.0.0/24 lb_net
docker network connect --ip=192.168.0.2 lb_net lb
docker exec -it lb /bin/bash
sudo docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -e DOMAINS="{my domain} -> http://192.168.0.2:80" --name https -itd --restart=always steveltn/https-portal --net lb_net  --ip=192.168.0.4
```

If you try this, steveltn/https-portal will continue to restart.
Put the logs here.

```
Parsing account key...
Parsing CSR...
Found domains: {domain}
Getting directory...
Directory found!
Registering account...
Registered!
Creating new order...
Order created!
Verifying apps.hashito.biz...
apps.hashito.biz verified!
Signing certificate...
Certificate signed!
Signed key for {domain}
[cont-init.d] 20-setup: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 30-set-docker-gen-status: executing... 
[cont-init.d] 30-set-docker-gen-status: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] done.
[services.d] starting services
[services.d] done.
ifelse: fatal: unable to exec -e: No such file or directory
[cmd] -e exited 127
s6-svscanctl: fatal: unable to control /var/run/s6/services: supervisor not listening
s6-svscanctl: fatal: unable to control /var/run/s6/services: supervisor not listening
[cont-finish.d] executing container finish scripts...
[cont-finish.d] done.
[s6-finish] waiting for services.
[s6-finish] sending all processes the TERM signal.
```

### try

I tried the following

- change `-e DOMAINS="{my domain} => http://192.168.0.2:80"`
- change `-e DOMAINS="{my domain} -> http://192.168.0.2"`
- Raise the specs of a running computer
- add  `-e STAGE=production`
- add  `-e FORCE_RENEW=true`
- change `steveltn/https-portal:1`
- delete the image and re-download
- PC restart

Comment: Anything after the image name (in your last `docker run` command, the `--net` and `--ip` options) is passed as command-line arguments to the image; Docker doesn't consider them.  The image name should be last unless you're overriding the command.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Correct the end to the image name.

Comment: @DavidMaze It was helpful. This was the cause.
I will close it

Answer (score 0):

Do not add Docker argument after Image name.

```
sudo docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -e DOMAINS="{my domain} -> http://192.168.0.2:80" --name https -itd --restart=always -e STAGE=production --net lb_net  --ip=192.168.0.4 steveltn/https-portal
```

This solved.
Thank you for your good advice.